# How to calculate the total entropy of dS black holes?

Tags: thermodynamics, black-holes, entropy, de-sitter-spacetime

In several articles where the thermodynamics of dS black holes have been investigated, the entropy part of the model or the total entropy has been analyzed based on the entropy of the black hole horizon and the cosmological horizon that be added an interaction term to it.
I checked many papers but could not find the first paper or work that led to the proof of such entropy. Does anyone know of the first work in this field?